# ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object laravel

Tags: php, laravel

umm hello.
Im new in laravel and i want to create a program for list of workers.

I'm trying to access this route:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/create`

and there's error message.

> ErrorException
>   Trying to get property '{"role":"pegawai","name":"asdasdasdasd1","email":"1asdad@ifocaproject.com","updated_at":"2020-05-11T18:26:31.000000Z","created_at":"2020-05-11T18:26:31.000000Z","id":7}' of non-object

this is my controller.

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {

        $user = new \App\User;
        $user->role = 'pegawai';
        $user->name = $request['nama_pegawai'];
        $user->email = $request['email'];
        $user->password = bcrypt('rahasia');
        $user->remember_token = Str::random(60);
        $user->save();

        $request ->request->add(['user_id'-> $user->id]);
        $pegawai = \App\Pegawai::create($request->all());
        return redirect('/pegawai')->with('sukses','Data Berhasil Di-input');
    }
```

and this is my blade.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form action="/pegawai/create" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Nama Pegawai</label>
            <input name="nama_pegawai" type="text" class="form-control"
                id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Joni">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email</label>
            <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control"
                id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="eve@ifocaprojec.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Jenis Kelamin</label>
            <select name="jenis_kelamin" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                <option value="Laki-Laki">Laki-laki</option>
                <option value="Perempuan">Perempuan</option>
                <option value="-none-">-none-</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Umur</label>
            <input name="umur" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cth:21">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Agama</label>
            <input name="agama" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cth:Islam">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Alamat</label>
            <textarea name="alamat" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Divisi</label>
            <select name="divisi" class="form-control">
                <option value="Inbound">Inbound</option>
                <option value="Outbound">Outbound</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

table user:

[image: table user]

table pegawai:

[image: table pegawai]

What Am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.
And I'm sorry, I'm not very good at English.

Comment: `add(['user_id'-> $user->id]);` You've got the wrong arrow there, should be `=>`, not `->`

Comment: There is no id in the user object, you can use ->create() instead of save();

Comment: @mohammad.kaab `$user->save()` method automatically gets insert id from DB and saves it in object

Comment: I think, save is returning boolean not an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have typo in code.
Here it must be `=>` instead of `->`:

```
$request->request->add(['user_id' => $user->id]);
```

Comment: While correct, this is better left as a comment (which it already is), as typo answers are unlikely to help others. Please consider flagging the question/voting to close as a typo/syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to reload data from DB after  ->save():

.......

```
$user->save();

$request ->request->add(['user_id'-> $user->fresh()->id]);
```

Comment: Incorrect. Model's created with `new Model()` followed by `->save()` will have a primary key assigned.